# Make cells same width and height to fill the table

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to learn how to use table layouts in android, this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- 3 columns -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="Column 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Column 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Column 3" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

How can I make the `TableRow` to fit the width of the `TableLayout` and the height to the `TableLayout` height? In simple words, I would like to have all columns with the same width and rows with the same height filling the `TableLayout`, is it possible? How?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to play with `weight` values. The xml for two rows would look like this.-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- 3 columns -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Column 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Column 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Column 3" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Column 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Column 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Column 3" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

And this is the result.-

[image]

---

As a side note, notice that `fill_parent` is deprecated, you should use `match_parent` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way would be to use `layout_weight` with the objects in your table row.  Here's how your xml should look after specifying it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- 3 columns -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Column 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Column 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Column 3" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

When using weight, you want to set the `layout_width` to 0dp so that it can override the actual value.  This split will give you each view taking up 1/3 of the TableRow.  Play around with the weight value until you've got something you like.

Answer (score -1):

add `android:layout_weight="0.3"` to the child's inside `TableRow`
try to replace your layout xml to this

hope this what you are looking for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- 3 columns -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:text="Column 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:text="Column 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:text="Column 3" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```